# Find the number in line. Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I find the number in line number may not be in the beginning. For example: "d: \ \ 1.jpg"

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to do a lot better at explaining what you require, or this might be closed. Try to tell us what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a Regular Expression with the [`RegExp`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) object:

```
var myRegEx = /\d+/; // RegEx to find one or more digits

var myMatch = myRegEx.exec("d:\\1.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var match = "testing 123".match(/\d/);
if (match) {
    alert(match.index); // alerts 8, the index of "1" in the string
}
```

That uses [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Match), passing in a literal regexp using the "digit" class (`\d`).

And/or you can grab all contiguous digits starting with the first digit found:

```
var match = "testing 123".match(/\d+/);
if (match) {
    alert(match.index); // alerts 8, the index of "1" in the string
    alert(match[0]);    // alerts "123"
}
```

Those links are to the Mozilla documentation because it's fairly good, but these are not Mozilla-specific features.